# Is it possible to set a canvas as foreground?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a simple html page like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"  href="images/icon.png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body bgcolor="ffffff"><br>

<img src="images/1.png" style="position:relative; left:4%; width:85%"></img>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="7; home.html" />

</body>
</html>
```

that displays an image and after 7 seconds redirects to the home page. I found a cool confetti code online that uses canvas and I would like to add it to this page in the foreground, but always being able to see the image or text I could add to the page in the future, but I can't find a way to do so. the confetti code is this:

```
(function() {
  var COLORS, Confetti, NUM_CONFETTI, PI_2, canvas, confetti, context, drawCircle, i, range, resizeWindow, xpos;

  NUM_CONFETTI = 350;

  COLORS = [[85, 71, 106], [174, 61, 99], [219, 56, 83], [244, 92, 68], [248, 182, 70]];

  PI_2 = 2 * Math.PI;

  canvas = document.getElementById("world");

  context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  window.w = 0;

  window.h = 0;

  resizeWindow = function() {
    window.w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    return window.h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  };

  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeWindow, false);

  window.onload = function() {
    return setTimeout(resizeWindow, 0);
  };

  range = function(a, b) {
    return (b - a) * Math.random() + a;
  };

  drawCircle = function(x, y, r, style) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, r, 0, PI_2, false);
    context.fillStyle = style;
    return context.fill();
  };

  xpos = 0.5;

  document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    return xpos = e.pageX / w;
  };

  window.requestAnimationFrame = (function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(callback) {
    return window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
  })();

  Confetti = (function() {
    function Confetti() {
      this.style = COLORS[~~range(0, 5)];
      this.rgb = "rgba(" + this.style[0] + "," + this.style[1] + "," + this.style[2];
      this.r = ~~range(2, 6);
      this.r2 = 2 * this.r;
      this.replace();
    }

    Confetti.prototype.replace = function() {
      this.opacity = 0;
      this.dop = 0.03 * range(1, 4);
      this.x = range(-this.r2, w - this.r2);
      this.y = range(-20, h - this.r2);
      this.xmax = w - this.r;
      this.ymax = h - this.r;
      this.vx = range(0, 2) + 8 * xpos - 5;
      return this.vy = 0.7 * this.r + range(-1, 1);
    };

    Confetti.prototype.draw = function() {
      var _ref;
      this.x += this.vx;
      this.y += this.vy;
      this.opacity += this.dop;
      if (this.opacity > 1) {
        this.opacity = 1;
        this.dop *= -1;
      }
      if (this.opacity < 0 || this.y > this.ymax) {
        this.replace();
      }
      if (!((0 < (_ref = this.x) && _ref < this.xmax))) {
        this.x = (this.x + this.xmax) % this.xmax;
      }
      return drawCircle(~~this.x, ~~this.y, this.r, "" + this.rgb + "," + this.opacity + ")");
    };

    return Confetti;

  })();

  confetti = (function() {
    var _i, _results;
    _results = [];
    for (i = _i = 1; 1 <= NUM_CONFETTI ? _i <= NUM_CONFETTI : _i >= NUM_CONFETTI; i = 1 <= NUM_CONFETTI ? ++_i : --_i) {
      _results.push(new Confetti);
    }
    return _results;
  })();

  window.step = function() {
    var c, _i, _len, _results;
    requestAnimationFrame(step);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    _results = [];
    for (_i = 0, _len = confetti.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      c = confetti[_i];
      _results.push(c.draw());
    }
    return _results;
  };

  step();

}).call(this);
```

Any suggestion or idea on how to have the confetti animation in the foreground but keeping the page fully functional in the background?

Comment: can u explain it bit more clearly,is it like  u want to keep the canvas element on top of an background image? or what exactly ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have a simple page with an image, but in the future maybe I want to add some text, or something, it is a page that is going to be upgraded maybe. I found the confetti animation in this webside: http://codepen.io/Shipow/pen/cEgiu and I thought it would look cool as a foreground (for example, in a congratulations page or something, it look better with falling confetti). So what I would need to have is the confetti effect as it was a transparent layer in top of everything but that not affects the functionality of the page (for example text, images, radio buttons...)

Comment: u already have an answer by making pointer-events: none u can click on the canvas element ,just add the canvas id in your html page and put pointer-events: none thats all done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible ...

### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wogar/1/edit)

#### CSS

```
pointer-events: none
```

- [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
<canvas id="world" style="position:absolute;z-index:3;pointer-events:none;"></canvas>
```

just add this to your html and the confetti part to a .js(your customized js)